# Nginx loading images very slow

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx

I am trying to load some high resolution images with Jpeg format and specs are 300dpi, 5000 x 5000 resolution in Django production. 
Following are my nginx settings at digitalocean:

```
upstream app_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /home/django/django_project;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name localhost;


    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # Your Django project's media files - amend as required
    location /media  {
        alias /home/django/django_project/media/;
    }

    # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location /static/django_project/ {
        alias /home/django/django_project/static/django_project/; 
    }
    # Django static images
    location /static/django_project/images {
        alias /home/django/django_project/static-only/django_project/images/;
    }


    # Proxy the static assests for the Django Admin panel
    location /static/admin {
       alias /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}
```

After Browsing cache enabled:

```
upstream app_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /home/django/django_project;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name mysite.com;


    keepalive_timeout 5;

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }

    # Your Django project's media files - amend as required
    location /media  {
        alias /home/django/django_project/media/;
    }

    # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location /static/django_project/ {
        alias /home/django/django_project/static/django_project/; 
    }
    # Django static images
    location /static/django_project/images {
        alias /home/django/django_project/static-only/django_project/images/;
    }


    # Proxy the static assests for the Django Admin panel
    location /static/admin {
       alias /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}
```

My images on live site are very slow to be loaded. Please advise or ref to some useful resource to fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Please use nginx Cache, this will solve your problem..

https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/

You can also cache the images in browser too by enabling browser cache...

https://www.howtoforge.com/make-browsers-cache-static-files-on-nginx

Comment: Sathik in "/path/to/cache" under "proxy_cache_path" directive where should I set my path and to what folder exactly. I am using Django and all my static files are located in different folder and my dynamic apps use a different location to upload an image from user.

Comment: as mentioned in the link please add them on top. Above to server { . Since you are serving static files to browser, dont need to be in app path.

Comment: As per your suggestion I added browsing cache and still problem persists. The way I added is under "After browsing cache enabled: in question area. Please advise.

Comment: This is one way approach and this will load for first time but will be faster next requests. But if image size is big need find an alternate. Can you let me know the sizes of images you are trying load?

Comment: These are high resolution images and most of the users expected to visit this site are MAC users. So I need high resolution images. Images are 5616 x 3744 with 300dpi and 24 bit depth. Format is Jpeg and all the images are around these specifications.

Comment: According to my static location can you let me know how to create "proxy_cache_path" so I can set directives accordingly. I used different paths but it didn't picked it up.

Comment: In the second part of you configuration, you have mentioned anything about Cache. Is that updated one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104023/discussion-between-shazia-nusrat-and-sathik-khan).

Comment: Sathik I've changed the images size as those images were really heavy so things worked as per communication over chat.